# Creating a heatmap based on historical map in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a data frame with several pre-1918 Russian districts ("Gouvernement") and the count of Waggons with relief aid going there:

```
df <- structure(list(Gouvernement = structure(c(31L, 22L, 19L, 13L, 
29L, 18L, 17L, 27L, 4L, 25L, 35L, 28L, 7L, 34L, 15L, 24L, 2L, 
10L, 16L, 23L, 8L, 6L, 26L, 3L, 20L, 1L, 32L, 14L, 12L, 30L, 
11L, 5L, 21L, 9L, 33L), .Label = c("Amur", "Astrachan", "Buchera", 
"Charkow", "Donsches Heeresgebiet", "Fergana", "Irkutsk", "Jennisejsk", 
"Kaluga", "Kasan", "Kostroma", "Minsk", "Moskau", "Nischnij Nowgorod", 
"Olonetz", "Orel", "Orenburg", "Pensa ", "Perm", "Priamur", "Rjasan", 
"Samara ", "Samarkand", "Saratow", "Semipalatinsk", "Simbirsk", 
"Syr-Darja", "Tobolsk", "Tomsk", "Trans-Kaspische Provinz", "Transbaikalien", 
"Turgai", "Twer ", "Ufa", "Wjatka"), class = "factor"), Waggons = c(118, 
75, 56, 46, 46, 40, 34, 32, 30, 26, 24, 22, 22, 20, 19, 18, 13, 
13, 13, 12, 12, 9, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)),
.Names = c("Gouvernement", "Waggons"), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see, there are some districts which received most of the Waggons, whereas others received only a small share:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Gouvernement, weight = Waggons)) +
        geom_bar() + 
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

I want to print a heatmap which colorizes the districts based on the share of Waggons received. This heatmap should be based on the following historic map:
[Map of the Russian Empire 194-1918](http://content.staatsbibliothek-berlin.de/dms/PPN755491602/1200/0/00000053.jpg) ([TIFF with 21 Mb](http://ngcs.staatsbibliothek-berlin.de/?action=metsImage&format=jpg&metsFile=PPN755491602&divID=PHYS_0053&original=true))

How can I digitize this map and use it for creating a heatmap with R?

I use a Mac, OS X Yosemite, R version 3.2.2, and R Studio Version 0.99.441.

Comment: Maybe check out https://www.google.com/search?q=image+to+shapefile first, to get the map right.

Comment: You can [use qgis](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/digitizing_basics.html) to make shapefiles from the raster and then use that as the basis for a choropleth (though it's fairly low res). That seems like alot of work to communicate what you're trying to communicate. A bar chart would work in lieu of this herculean task. Alternatively, you could import the raster into qgis, define spatial points approximately at the centers of the 35 districts and use log-scaled sized bubbles (if you _really_ need to use a map).

Comment: But isn't there an easier way to tag the districts (or district borders) and tell R to fill the districts with colors based on these tags?